# Gif animation does not work on Yocto Pyro in Qt 5.8. How to build qtbase 5.8 in bitbake with libqgif.so?

Tags: linux, qt5, gif, yocto, bitbake

QT5 application, compiled in bitbake for Yocto Fido (QT 5.4) works well with GIF animation. The same application compiled for Yocto Pyro (QT 5.8) does not display GIF animation (QLabel is empty). There is no libqgif.so library, located in /usr/lib/qt5/plugins/imageformats/ (This library is related to qtbase). When I copy libqgif.so from rootfs with QT 5.4. to rootfs with QT 5.8 - animation works. How to build qtbase 5.8 in bitbake with libqgif.so for Yocto Pyro?

Comment: we have no idea which Qt versions have you used and how you've compiled libs and images, therefore it's absolutely impossible to answer your question

Comment: @Iridiumus you should edit the question and put the additional information and question there, instead of a comment

Answer (score 1):

Add **qtbase_%.bbapend** with content just:

```
PACKAGECONFIG_append = " gif"
```